# Choosing a Singleton or a Category?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, singleton, categories

Fairly early on in my app, when I was a lot less experienced than I am now, I wanted to spice up some transitions between view controllers with my own custom animations.  Having no idea where to start, I looked around SO for a pattern like MVC that could be accessed from nearly any controller at any time, and as it turns out, a singleton was the way to go.

What I didn't realize is that there seems to be a strong and well-defended hatred of the singleton pattern, and I myself am starting to see why, but that is beside the point.

So, a while later, I decided to move my very same implementation into a category on UINavigationController (after all, it handles transitions!), kept the original classes around for comparison, and am wondering which method would work best.  Having thoroughly tested both implementations, I can say without a doubt that they are equal in every way, including speed, accuracy, smoothness, frame-rate, memory usage, etc.  so which one is 'better' in the sense of overall maintainability?

**EDIT:** after reading the well-written arguments you all have made, I have decided to use a singleton.  @JustinXXVII has made the most convincing argument (IMHO), although I consider every answer here equally worthy of merit.  Thank you all for your opinions, I have upvoted all answers in the question.

Comment: Not sure why responders to this question don't seem to understand what a category is. It is a part of the Objective C language: http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html

Comment: @ThomasW, Categories are a way to extend ObjC classes. While in the old days (ObjC1) they were used to handle things we use protocols for today, they're a separate (and very useful thing. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll make the case for a singleton object. Singletons are used all over `UIKit` and `iOS`. One thing you can't do with categories is add instance variables. There are two things about this:

1. MVC workflows don't tolerate objects with intimate knowledge of other objects
2. Sometimes you just need a place to reference an object that doesn't really belong anywhere else

These things go against each other, but the added ability to be able to keep an instance variable that doesn't really have an "owner" is why I favor the singleton.

I usually have one singleton class in all of my XCode projects, which is used to store "global" objects and do mundane things that I don't want to burden my AppDelegate with.

An example would be serializing/archiving objects and unarchiving/restoring. I have to use the same method throughout several classes, I don't want to extend UIViewController with some serializing method to write and read arbitrary files. Maybe it's just my personal preference.

I also might need a quick way to lookup information in NSUserDefaults but not want to always be writing `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"blah"]`, so I will just declare a method in my singleton that takes a string argument.

Until now i've not really thought too much about using a category for these things. One thing is sure though, I'd rather not be instantiating a new object a hundred times to do the same task when I can have just one living object that sticks around and will take care of stuff for me. (Without burdening the AppDelegate)

Comment: I thought more about this yesterday and I am seeing the better side of using a category. It fits your implementation better than a singleton does.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the best option is use the category.

Because if you are already using UINavigationController, do not make sense create a new class that will only manage the transition, like you told: `(after all, it handles transitions!)`

This will be a better option to maintain your code, and you will be sure that the thing do what they expect to do, and if you already have an instance that do the transitions, why create another?

The design patterns, like singleton, factory, and others, need to be used with responsibility. In your case, I do not see why use a singleton, you use it only to no instantiate new objects, you do not really need to have only one instance of it, but you do it because you want only one.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the real question is in "design" (as you said, both codes work fine), and by writing down your problem in simple sentences, you will find your answer :

- singleton's purpose is to have only one instance of a class running in your app. So you can share things between objects. (one available to many objects)
- category purpose is to extend the methods available to **a** class. (available to one class of objects only ! ok...objects from subclasses too)

what you really want is to make a new transition available to UINavigationController class. UINavigationController, which has already some method available to change view (present modal views, addsubviews, etc.) is built to manage views with transitions (you said it yourself, it handles transitions), all you want to do is **adding another way of handling transitions for your navigation controllers** thus you would preferably use a category.

My opinion is that what you want to achieve is covered by the category and by doing this you ensure that the only objects which are accessing this method are entitled to use it. With the singleton pattern, any object of any class could call your singleton and its methods (and... it could work nobody knowing how for an OS version n but your app could be broken in n+1 version).

Answer (score 2):

In this implementation, for which there is no need to use a Singleton, there may be no difference at all. That doesn't mean that there isn't one.

A plastic bucket holds as much water as a metal bucket does, and it does it just as well. In that aspect there seems to be no difference between the two. However, if you try to transport something extremely hot, the plastic bucket might not do the job so well..

What I'm trying to say is, they both serve their purposes but in your case there seemed to be no difference because the task was too generic. You wanted a method that was available from multiple classes, and both solutions can do that.

In your case, however, it might be a whole of a lot simpler to use a Category. The implementation is easier and you (possibly) need less code.

But if you were to create a data manager that holds an array of objects that you ONLY want available at one place, a Category will not be up to the task. That's a typical Singleton task.
Singeltons are single-instance objects (and if made static, available from nearly everywhere). Categories are extensions to your existing classes and limited to the class it extends.

To answer your question; choose a Category.

*A subclass might also work, but has its own pros and cons

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply create a base UIViewController subclass and extend all of your view controllers from this object? A category doesn't make sense for this purpose.

Comment: Tight schedule of release+108 classes and counting = will work on this later.

Comment: Find and replace? ": UIViewController" with ": BaseViewController".

Comment: I'm deeply entrenched in the bug-fixing stage of the next version.  I simply have no time to write, then debug, a new class.

Answer (score 1):

Singletons, as the name suggests, has to be used when there is a need to be *exactly one object* in your application. The pattern for the accessor method ensures only this requirement being a class method:

```
+ (MyClass*) sharedInstance
{
    static MyClass *instance = nil;
    if (instance == nil)  instance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    return instance;
}
```

If implemented well, the class also ensures that its constructor is private thus nobody else can instantiate the class but the accessor method: this ensures that at any time at most one instance of the class exists. The best example of such class is `UIApplication` since at any time there might be only one object of this class.

The point here is that this is the only requirement towards singleton. The role of the accessor method is to ensure that there is only one instance, and not that it would provide access to that instance from everywhere. It is only a *side effect* of the pattern that, the accessor method being static, everybody can access this single object without having a reference (pointer) to it a priori. Unfortunately this fact is widely abused by Objective C programmers and this leads to messed up design and the hatred towards singleton pattern you mentioned. But all in all it is not the fault the singleton patter but the misuse of their accessor method.

Now turning back to your question: if you don't need static / global variables in your custom transition code (I guess you don't) then the answer is definitely go for categories. In C++ you would subclass from some parent BaseTransition class and implement your actual drawing methods. Objective C has categories (that in my opinion is another way that easily messes up the design, but they are much more convenient) where you can add custom functionality even accessing the variables of your host class. Use them whenever you can redeem singletons with them and don't use singletons when the main requirement towards your class is not that it would be only one instance of it.